# How to make aspx web pages to adjust with browser window size?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have old version of Microsoft Visual Studio.NET (2003) on Windows Server 2003.
I have to manage a Pre-developed database pages. The pages (.aspx) seem to be static and not adjust web page size as per window size of browser and remains aligned towards left. This looks old fashioned.
How can I improve the page by making its size and alignment flexible?
(Note: Unfortunately I can not upgrade any of OS or VS.NET)

Comment: ASP.Net is a server-side technology. Layout required client-side technologies... You would need to understand HTML and CSS for this task.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by using CSS & You need to apply the css in pecentage and not in pixels then it will be compatible with any browser and also with the mobile.
you will not have to scroll to left or right after applying the proper CSS.

But to achieve this you need to apply proper css to your webpage.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is the example of Developing your webpage with css in percentage wise manner. If you make your screen of your browser to small then also you will not have to scroll left or right it will automatically adjusted.